# How to use error variable and error action in this cmd New-ADOrganizationalUnit

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use error action on powershell command `New-ADOrganizationUnit`. I want continue silently `-EA SilentlyContinue`. I am able to do for other commands.

`PS C:\Users\154948> New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $INNCODE -Path "OU=???,OU=???,DC=??,DC=???,DC=???,DC=???" -ea SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable myerror`

> New-ADOrganizationalUnit : The term 'New-ADOrganizationalUnit' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the  spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $INNCODE -Path "OU=???,OU=???,DC ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-ADOrganizationalUnit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

`PS C:\Users\154948> Stop-Process "13" -ea SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable myerror`

```
PS C:\Users\154948> $myerror
```

> Stop-Process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier 13.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Stop-Process "13" -ea SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable myerror
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (13:Int32) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand

Regards,

Nikita

Comment: This is completely un-readable.

Comment: The error you get tells you what you should do... "Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. ". What are you trying to read from `$INNCODE` ?

Comment: @Modro $INNCODE doesn't matter since the cmdlet isn't loaded at all.

Comment: Start with... Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Answer (score 0):

`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` is **never** going to work on a cmdlet that PowerShell doesn't recognize.

Make sure you have the ActiveDirectory module loaded and try again.